# Solution to this non linear Equation

Tags: solution-verification, characteristic-functions

Hi all I have this equation
$$
(y-\beta+2\beta e^{yd})(y+\beta -2 \beta e^{-yd})+\beta^2=0 
$$

Solving for y, I have been told that the solution is y = 0 repeated roots. I can see why (from observation) for one root but where is the second root coming from?

Comment: should this equation be solved for $y$?

Comment: for what stand the variables here?

Comment: Yes. Solve for y